# How to access Azure Database from Azure Batch?

Tags: azure, azure-batch, azure-database-mysql

I have a Java process inside a Docker container inside an Azure Batch Task.

The Java process is trying to simply establish a JDBC database connection to the Azure Database for MySQL service.

The connection error includes 'Client with IP address '52.224..(etc)' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.'

Therefore, I am attempting to learn how to give Azure Batch tasks the ability to connect to Azure Database for MySQL. I cannot find any documentation that seems to address this challenge.

I can see that Azure Database for MySQL contains IP-based firewall settings - but do not know how this would be used to allow access from Azure Batch tasks. Since Azure Batch procures the Virtual Machine - I will have no idea what the IP address is ahead of time in order to add it to database firewall rules.  I also don't want add a range of IP addresses that gives other Azure accounts connectivity to this database,

In AWS, this problem is handled with role-based access to the database. Each AWS Batch instance is assignable to a role with access to whatever AWS resources it needs.

I have found no helpful documentation to solve this problem with Azure Batch in a similar way and MS Support has not been helpful - providing me a list of all possible Azure IP addresses - presumably to add to our firewall rules (impractical and insecure).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. The most straightforward way is to use [virtual network service endpoint for the MySQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/concepts-data-access-and-security-vnet) ([example via Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/howto-manage-vnet-using-portal)) and use the same virtual network (typically in a different subnet) for the [Azure Batch Pool Compute Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-virtual-network).
2. You can bring your own [ARM-based Public IP addresses for an Azure Batch Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/create-pool-public-ip) and use those Public IP Addresses within the [IP filtering/ACLs on the MySQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/concepts-data-access-and-security-vnet#b-ip-rules).

Comment: Thanks - I'll pursue option 1.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Portal, created a Private Endpoint Connection for the database, which includes assignment of a private IP address.  Azure Batch configuration can then reference the private IP of the database in the JDBC connection - assuming Batch Pool is referencing the same subnet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns